# live migration using KVM

Tags: migration, device, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I want live migration of virtual machines between two host and for that i am using following command:

```
virsh migrate  vmtest qemu+ssh://root@10.20.254.106/system
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
error: internal error process exited while connecting to monitor: char device redirected to /dev/pts/3
qemu: could not open disk image /vms/vmtest.qcow2: No such file or directory
```

/vms/vmtest.qcow2 is the harddisk image of the virtual machine i want to migrate
The configuration of both the hosts is exactly same form machine architecture to qemu version. I haven't disturbed any iptables settings on any of the hosts. Default network is active on both the hosts. Is there any thing wrong in the command or if this error messages means something (not to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a nfs pool or any other kind of shared hostage and try doing the migration.

Comment: I am confused that if i have to migrate a vm from host A to B then i have to mount A's vm-storage on B or vice-versa.
Other doubt is that as people say the two location should be having the same url for migration, its unclear, if somebody could guide me.

Comment: @Jatin Kumar- Please check [this](http://preethiramesh.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/live-migration-using-libvirts-java-api/)
The only difference is that you've got to substitute Libvirt commands with virsh commands.